# Is there a composition rule for connections?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

The exterior derivative satisfies the property

$d(f\circ g)=df\circ dg$,

which is the generalization of the chain rule (dg and df are taken at the points a and g(a) respectively).  Is there a generalization of this rule to connections?  In other words, is there a context in which the following chain rule makes sense

$\nabla_{f\circ g}(f\circ g)=\nabla_f f\circ \nabla_g g$

where different connections are defined for each map.  Naturally the third connection would have to be related to the other two in some way.  Would this composed connection be uniquely defined?

Comment: Why don't you start by establishing the ground rules? Are talking about connections on vector bundles with $f$ and $g$ representing respective sections? What bundles would this make sense for?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether it would make sense or not.  That’s basically why I’m asking the question.  The answer might be that it doesn’t make sense - it probably doesn’t make sense for a usual notion of fiber bundle.

Comment: Well, I wanted you to give some thought to what might be a meaningful setting. You would need something like a vector bundle $E$ and a bundle of maps $\text{Hom}(E,F)$, Then, given a section $\sigma$ of $E$ and a section $\tau$ of $\text{Hom}(E,F)$, $\tau\circ\sigma$ would give you a section of $F$.

Comment: Sure, yes I agree.  I have thought about it (it is part of an idea for a research project I am working on).  You could also consider an affine bundle whose sections are maps, and define a connection on the affine bundle, then the composition of two of these sections would be another map.  But then it is not clear what a connection would be on this bundle (you may not find global sections, but could you still consider a type of composition of connections?).  i was wondering if there were papers on this type of idea.  But also your construction works too.  It's kind of an open ended question.

Comment: You could also consider the composition of two bundle maps, which would probably induce a map on the horizontal subspaces of the maps.  I have thought about these constructions, they are possible but I just wanted to see if I was reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is all pretty standard stuff with induced connections on tensor products of vector bundles and the product rule for contractions. I din't think the horizontal subspace viewpoint is so helpful here.